# Could I thread this for loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

```
for(unsigned int mBlock = 0; mBlock < coords.size(); mBlock++)
{   
    WidgetType widgetType; 
    height = macBlockWidth + coords[mBlock].y;
    width = macBlockHeight + coords[mBlock].x;

    macBlockParent = new QWidget;
    cooefsLink = new QPushButton(macBlockParent);
    macBlock = new QWidget(macBlockParent);
    widgetType.widget = macBlock;
    widgetType.type = (macBlocks[mBlock][2] != 'S') 
                        ? (macBlocks[mBlock][0]) : (macBlocks[mBlock][2]);
    blockWidgetTypes.push_back(widgetType);

    connect(cooefsLink, SIGNAL(released()), 
                                    this, SLOT(showCoefficients()));
    buttonSignals[cooefsLink] = mBlock;

    constructMotionVector(mBlock);
    macBlockLayout->addWidget(macBlockParent, height - 16, width - 16);
    styleMacroBlocks(mBlock);
}
```

could I make a function out of this for loop where I could parallel the operation by splitting it into two different for loops both operating on the vector at the same time. One working on the first half items and the second thread building the second half. So for example

**Thread 1**

```
for(unsigned int mBlock = 0; mBlock < coords.size() / 2; mBlock++)
{   
    WidgetType widgetType; 
    height = macBlockWidth + coords[mBlock].y;
    width = macBlockHeight + coords[mBlock].x;

    macBlockParent = new QWidget;
    cooefsLink = new QPushButton(macBlockParent);
    macBlock = new QWidget(macBlockParent);
    widgetType.widget = macBlock;
    widgetType.type = (macBlocks[mBlock][2] != 'S') 
                        ? (macBlocks[mBlock][0]) : (macBlocks[mBlock][2]);
    blockWidgetTypes.push_back(widgetType);

    connect(cooefsLink, SIGNAL(released()), 
                                    this, SLOT(showCoefficients()));
    buttonSignals[cooefsLink] = mBlock;

    constructMotionVector(mBlock);
    macBlockLayout->addWidget(macBlockParent, height - 16, width - 16);
    styleMacroBlocks(mBlock);
}
```

**Thread 2**

```
for(unsigned int mBlock = coords.size() / 2; mBlock < coords.size(); mBlock++)
{   
    WidgetType widgetType; 
    height = macBlockWidth + coords[mBlock].y;
    width = macBlockHeight + coords[mBlock].x;

    macBlockParent = new QWidget;
    cooefsLink = new QPushButton(macBlockParent);
    macBlock = new QWidget(macBlockParent);
    widgetType.widget = macBlock;
    widgetType.type = (macBlocks[mBlock][2] != 'S') 
                        ? (macBlocks[mBlock][0]) : (macBlocks[mBlock][2]);
    blockWidgetTypes.push_back(widgetType);

    connect(cooefsLink, SIGNAL(released()), 
                                    this, SLOT(showCoefficients()));
    buttonSignals[cooefsLink] = mBlock;

    constructMotionVector(mBlock);
    macBlockLayout->addWidget(macBlockParent, height - 16, width - 16);
    styleMacroBlocks(mBlock);
}
```

Because its a real bottleneck for my system and I notice its only using one CPU and its maxing out that CPU. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Also I should mention I know the simplistic example I put up isn't very threadsafe, like for example I'd need two different pointers for macBlockParent, for example macBlockParentT1 and macBlockParentT2.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see what it is that eats up CPU? I'm unfamiliar with QT, so all I see in this code is some creation of widgets/controls - that shouldn't be a bottleneck, right? Where exactly is it?

Comment: The bottleneck is in the for loop creating the widgets, on smaller resolution videos its zippy but I'm working on a larger res now and it takes ages to build the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... If you have constructions like this: `blockWidgetTypes.push_back(widgetType);` in **both** threads, it's seems very dangerous for multithreaded execution.

Comment: I could take that out, I understand thats quite dangerous but assuming that wasn't a concern how would I best approach this?

Comment: @DavidTr, I don't see any simple solution here.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway, It's really causing a bottleneck for my system.